# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=3.0.0.0 in Azure Functions App v3

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a v3 queue-triggered function that has been working fine on my Windows 10 machine. This is how the .csproj file looks like:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I am not sure why I started getting the exception mentioned in the subject line, but the bottom line is that this function used to work well. [This Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089282/azure-function-v3-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependen) was not helpful to address the issue. Could it be due to upgrading the operating system to Windows 11? I did not run this function app immediately after migrating to Windows 11, so I cannot speak on that.

The full exception's stack trace is per below:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> at
> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.FunctionsStartup.Configure(WebJobsBuilderContext
> context, IWebJobsBuilder builder)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.ConfigureStartup(IWebJobsStartup
> startup, WebJobsBuilderContext context, IWebJobsBuilder builder) in
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs:line
> 162

Any idea on what the possible solution would be as it has become a roadblock?

Answer (score 1):

To preserve specific version in order to avoid upgrading to a newer version which you could add this entry to csproj

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput> to the Function's project file.

like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```